# Get current location from osx/cocoa app using xcode swift 3

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift3, mapkit

I apologize for not providing it with a code. The reason I posted it with images because xcode is **LLVM(low level virtual machine)** compiler which has mostly **UI environment** especially for the **configuration part**. Such as creating either an outlet or action for object by dragging them to the view controller instead defining it by a code directly. Thus since it was so, I think people would easily notice my mistake faster.

```
import Cocoa
import MapKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

   @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
   var locManager = CLLocationManager()
   var currentLocation = CLLocation()

   var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   var didFindMyLocation = false
   var strForCurLatitude = "";
   var strForCurLongitude = "";

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let distancespan:CLLocationDegrees = 2000
       let busCScampuslocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D =  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
       mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: bsuCScampuslocation, latitudinalMeters: distancespan, longitudinalMeters: distancespan), animated: true)
       print(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images, post code (text). Your `currentLocation` is declared empty. You have to set the delegate of the `CLLocationManager` then call `startUpdatingLocation()` to get the current location via the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method. Please read the documentation of [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager)

Comment: I thank you for your response, but could you please explain in code about setting the delegate of the CLLocationManager? Or you can reply it in via answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift 5:

ViewController.swift

```
import Cocoa
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

       let manager = CLLocationManager()

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           manager.delegate = self
           manager.startUpdatingLocation()
       }

       func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            print(locations)
            //This is where you can update the MapView when the computer is moved (locations.last!.coordinate)
       }

       func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            print(error)
       }

       func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                     didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
           print("location manager auth status changed to: " )
           switch status {
               case .restricted:
                    print("restricted")
               case .denied:
                    print("denied")
               case .authorized:
                    print("authorized")
               case .notDetermined:
                    print("not yet determined")
               default:
                    print("Unknown")
       }

}
```

Add these lines to Info.plist or set the `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` and/(or?) `NSLocationUsageDescription` to a plaintext description of why you need to access the users location

```
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Allows us to locate you</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Allows us to locate you</string>
```

If the user has Location Services off, the authorization status will be 'denied'

Comment: Did you try this on macos?